# Moving apps from android phone to nobis tablet

Tags: applications

Is it possible to transfer the apps from my phone the HUAWEI Raven H892L to my NOBIS NB09 tablet if I hook them both to my laptop even though I don't have internet ? I really need the help on my nobis tablet I have two internal storages one is empty and the other is maxed out full but nothing is downloaded onto it no apps except for the ones that came on it So what does anyone say about all this.

Answer (score 0):

Possible by copying APKs from Huawei to Nobus.

Download one of the many apk extractors on the Google play and extract the APK of the apps you want to transfer.

Connect the Huawei device into the computer through MTP Mass Storage and copy the extracted APK to the computer then to the Nobus.

Comment: Awesome I will give it a try